# Read dictionary from a text file in a tabular form

Tags: python, file

I have successfully written a dictionary in a text file but i am not able to read it.

```
l={}
a=0
lo=eval(input("enter no of times"))
for i in range (lo):
    name=str(input('Enter name'))
    sal=eval(input('Enter sal'))
    no=eval(input('Enter no'))
    acsal=sal*no
    a=a+acsal
    l.update({name:acsal})
print(a)
print (l)
f=open("try.txt","w+")
f.write("BILL\n")
f.write(str(l))
f.write(a)
print (f.read())
f.close()
```

moreover i wanted the output to be shown in a tabular format for eg. if the file has a dictionary {"a":50,"b":60}
i wanted it to be read as :

```
a  50
b  60
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow! Please provide minimal reproducible code to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, eval is not what you should use.

Convert to specific types instead.

Second, use json or jaml. Those are made by people way smarter than me or you.